# WPF TouchDown Event Delay

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-4.0

Quite simply, I am experiencing an unacceptable delay on receiving TouchDown events on my UserControl in WPF4. My understanding of the event stack is that PreviewTouchDown gets sent first but it's still taking approximately 300ms-500ms. Code is below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" 
         d:DesignWidth="300" 
         Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"
         PreviewTouchDown="ProcessPreviewTouchDown"
         PreviewTouchUp="ProcessPreviewTouchUp">
</UserControl>
```

I've also added the following to my Window code:

```
num = GlobalAddAtom(atom);
if (num == 0L)
{
   return false;
}
if (enable)
{
   return (RemoveProp(hWnd, atom).ToInt64() == 1L);
}
else
{
   int TABLET_DISABLE_PRESSANDHOLD        = 0x00000001;
   int TABLET_DISABLE_PENTAPFEEDBACK      = 0x00000008;
   int TABLET_DISABLE_PENBARRELFEEDBACK   = 0x00000010;
   int TABLET_DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEOFF     = 0x00000200;
   int TABLET_DISABLE_FLICKS              = 0x00010000;

   int dwHwndTabletProperty = 0x1010019 |
                    TABLET_DISABLE_PRESSANDHOLD |
                    TABLET_DISABLE_PENTAPFEEDBACK | 
                    TABLET_DISABLE_TOUCHUIFORCEOFF |
                    TABLET_DISABLE_PENBARRELFEEDBACK |
                    TABLET_DISABLE_FLICKS;

   return (SetProp(hWnd, atom, new IntPtr(dwHwndTabletProperty)) == 1);
}
```

This certainly removes the UI but has causes no visible speed increase (even though TABLET_DISABLE_PRESSANDHOLD is supposed to but I suspect this is the same as adding `Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"` to the XAML).

If anyone has any pointers on how to make this delay disappear, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Where did you add that code ?